# Bootstrap row custom height in percentage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height, row

I'm developing a little website and I'm facing some troubles.

What I want is to resize a "row" div with a particular height, in percentage.
I've already searched on SO but nothing was good for me.
Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      ...
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row row-first">
          <img class="img img-responsive" src="public/img/bg.jpg" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

class "row-first" for now has no rules so it not take effect.
I want that "row-first" div is 80% of the viewport's height, but the only way to resize it is by putting some content inside the div so that the div's height follows content height.
my CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

.container-fluid {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height:80%;
}

.row-first {

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The height of the div is relative to the height of the parent. Therefor, to make the height of .row 80%, I first set the height of the parent. Here's the css:

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.row-first {
  height:80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmwoLkdr/

Feel free to play with the height and see for yourself!

Comment: Hi pgruber, thank for the reply, but my problem is that I want 80% of the viewport, i.e. the 80% of the visible browser's height. Using your approach I can modify correctly height, but the .container-fluid rule (height:100%) allows the container-fluid going outside the viewport height (i.e. the scrollbar appears).

Comment: Can't you just define a subcontainer of `.container-fluid` and set `height: 80%;` like in his example?